# Degrees of freedom in general full factorial design of experiments with missing observations

Tags: anova, experiment-design, degrees-of-freedom

I am trying to calculate the total sum of squares SST and the degrees of freedom of an experiment with four features and three levels for each feature. It results in 3x3x3x3 samples (of course). However, some observations are missing (e.g., 9 samples).
I am using the following regression Model.

```
            y = a + b + c + d + ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd + e
```

where
y -> estimated response
a -> effect related to factor a
b -> effect related to factor b
...
ab -> effect related to the interaction between a and b
...
high level interaction are not considered in my model.

My question is how to evaluate the degrees of freedom in this case as there are missing values.